# Registar un plan dependiendo de la fecha actual

Tags: laravel

Trabajo en laravel, y necesito hacer lo siguiente que un plan se registre si la fechaFin de la bd es es mayor a la fecha actual. Lo he intendado de esta manera:

```
$fechaFin = $buscar->fechaFinal; //obtenieno el dato de la base de datos
```

y validando estaticamente la fecha actual

```
if ($fechaFin >=  '2018-06-18') { 
        $plan = new PlanesPago;
        $plan->codigoPlan=$request->get('codigoPlan');
        $plan->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
        $plan->idCiclo=$request->get('idCiclo');
        $plan->save();

    }else{

         return json_encode("No Puedes Crear Otro Plan en  un mismo Periodo");

    }
```

pero no hace la validación y registra.

Comment: ¿Te sale algún error?

Comment: no unicamente no pasa la validación y registra

Comment: que es lo que te devuelve al imprimir `dd($fechaFin)`. Tal ves tienes una fecha menor a '2018-06-18' y por eso no entra al if

Comment: me imprime "2018-08-07"  si coloco   dd($fechaFin >= '2018-06-18'); me devuelve true

Comment: El problema es que estas comparando 2 String literales, no 2 fechas. PHP no entiende que eso es una fecha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes comparar fechas directamente. Lo que esta pasando en tu código es que php esta comparado 2 String no dos fechas.

Para comparar fechas, te puedes apoyar en la clase `DateTime` que php proporciona.

Ejemplo:

```
$hoy = new DateTime(); // Fecha actual
$fechaFin = new DateTime($buscar->fechaFinal); // Fecha bd

if ($fechaFin >=  $hoy) { 
    echo 'La fecha es mayor o igual a hoy';
} else { 
    echo 'la fecha es menor a hoy';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El gestor de fechas de Laravel es [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).
Te pondre un par de ejemplos para que veas el funcionamiento y puedas hacer todo lo que quieres.

- Fecha actual

  $hoy = Carbon::now();
- Compara fecha

  $primera = Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 23, 26, 11);

  $segunda= Carbon::create(2012, 9, 5, 20, 26, 11, 'America/Vancouver');

  if($primera->gt($segunda)) // bool(false)
  {
  // Mayor
  }